# Android: ClassNotFoundException with no change in code

Tags: java, android, exception, android-studio

I've been approached with a new crash in our Android application when trying to select an existing picture in the device and attempting to crop it. The code managing this was written over a year ago and seems to no longer work. Here is the logcat of the issue:

http://pastebin.com/q9prnYJj

Here are the manifests for both my library and the main project:

First manifest (library where the error is occurring):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tactio.tactiolib"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="6.6.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Second manifest (main project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tactio.tactiohealth"
    android:versionCode="22"
    android:versionName="6.6.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.tactio.tactiohealth.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.tactio.tactiohealth.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.tactio.tactiohealth.TthApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/tactiohealth"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/TactioAppTheme" >
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioUserProfileActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioEditHistoryActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioBackupLoginActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioRiskParametersActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioRiskPageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioThcLoginActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioJournalActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioGoalsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioExtendedGoalsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioWeightPageActivity" >
        </activity> 
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioWeightPlanActivity" >
        </activity> 
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioHomeActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioStepsPageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioPhysicalActivityActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioBloodOxygenPageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioSleepPageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioMoodPageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioPressurePageActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioCholesterolActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioGlucoseActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioConnectedHealthDeviceActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioReportActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:name="com.tactio.appObjects.graphing.TactioGraphActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioCHDoAuthSetupActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="oauth"
                    android:scheme="twpfitbitauthorize" />
                <data
                    android:host="oauth"
                    android:scheme="twpfitbugauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="oauth"
                    android:scheme="twpjawboneauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="oauth"
                    android:scheme="twpmovesauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="oauth"
                    android:scheme="twprunkeeperauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="dump.html"
                    android:scheme="twpwithingsauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="dump.html"
                    android:scheme="twpihealthauth" />
                 <data
                    android:host="auth"
                    android:scheme="twpgarminauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="dump.html"
                    android:scheme="twptactioauth" />
                <data
                    android:host="dump.html"
                    android:scheme="twpbmauth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioWelcomePage"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioWebActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioAppHasExpired" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioInfoSupportActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioSettingsActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioLifesaverActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioEulaActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioSwitchUserActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioPasscodeActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioDiabetesWizardActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="com.tactio.tactioActivities.TactioBodyTemperatureActivity" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried cleaning the project with Gradle from command line (using Android Studio) but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added the manifest.xml files.

Comment: verify that the pixel resolution of your images are just the minimum necessary for your layout. Try with another image to see if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you rename package to file com.tactio.appObjectsTWSpecific.views.TactioChdUpdateView

Comment: Do you mean change the name of my package to com.tactio.appObjectsTWSpecific.views.TactioChdUpdateView ?